# Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3]

Tags: java, android-studio, runtime-error

[Here's the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0GEK.png)

An Error is coming again and again whenever I start my chatting app. I used the tutorial from GetStream
But now it doesn't run plz help me.

The Error is:

> Could not find method classpath() for arguments [com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Its in the project level `build.gradle` file

Comment: Avoid posting pictures of code, instead insert your code in textual format. I'll help others in debugging you error.

Comment: post your build.gradle files